# I try convert this cURL code in code for Retrofit2 but I can't

Tags: json, curl, kotlin

I try convert this cURL in kotlin with retrofit2, but I can't.

```
'curl -X POST \
URL_BASE\
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
“process”: “Attended”,
“rauthorityId”: “<your_rauthorityId>”
 }'
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)? It uses examples to show how to create a request while setting a request type, headers, and a body. It doesn't explain how to integrate with Android specifically, but searching for 'retrofit2 tutorial' gives me plenty of results that do.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are having trouble with. When you run that code, what happens? If your problem is converting it, may we see the start of your conversion work?